# Package installation using pip gives "DuplicateOptionError"

Tags: pip, python-3.6, apple-m1

Hie everyone, I'm on a M1 mac with a python version 3.9.6
Whenever I try to "pip install package" I get the following error(inside or outside a virtual environment):

> ERROR: Exception:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 164, in exc_logging_wrapper
> status = run_func(*args)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 205, in wrapper
> return func(self, options, args)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 255, in run
> options.use_user_site = decide_user_install(
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 666, in decide_user_install
> if site_packages_writable(root=root_path, isolated=isolated_mode):
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 612, in site_packages_writable
> for d in set(get_lib_location_guesses(root=root, isolated=isolated))
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 598, in get_lib_location_guesses
> scheme = get_scheme(
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations/**init**.py", line 208, in get_scheme
> old = _distutils.get_scheme(
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations/_distutils.py", line 130, in get_scheme
> scheme = distutils_scheme(dist_name, user, home, root, isolated, prefix)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations/_distutils.py", line 46, in distutils_scheme
> d.parse_config_files()
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 406, in parse_config_files
> parser.read(filename)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/configparser.py", line 697, in read
> self._read(fp, filename)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/configparser.py", line 1096, in _read
> raise DuplicateOptionError(sectname, optname,
> configparser.DuplicateOptionError: While reading from '/Users/ayusharma/.pydistutils.cfg' [line  3]: option 'include_dirs' in section 'build_ext' already exists

Even when I try to create a new venv with the command "python3.9 -m venv tvenv":

> Error: Command '['/Users/ayusharma/Desktop/Textractor/tvenv/bin/python3.9', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

I am unable to install any python library due to this issue, does anyone know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution...
The configuration file i.e. `'/Users/ayusharma/.pydistutils.cfg'` had two similar keys which was causing the `DuplicateOptionError`

So I went into the file and removed the duplicate line, which solved the issue for me.

Just go into the config file:

```sh
vim /Users/ayusharma/.pydistutils.cfg (or any editor you use)
```

Check for duplicate lines if any just delete one.